# Spring Security 6.2 and CAS authentication : what happened to CasAuthenticationFilter.CAS_STATEFUL_IDENTIFIER?

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, cas

I'm setting up CAS authentication on my application using Spring Security 6.2.

The documentation (https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/authentication/cas.html) states:

> The processing filter will construct a UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken representing the service ticket. The principal will be equal to CasAuthenticationFilter.CAS_STATEFUL_IDENTIFIER, whilst the credentials will be the service ticket opaque value.

However, it seems that in version 6 of Spring Security, the CAS_STATEFUL_IDENTIFIER member has disappeared from the CasAuthenticationFilter class.

So, what's the best way to create this UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Spring Security 6.1.0, the `CasAuthenticationFilter` creates an instance of `CasServiceTicketAuthenticationToken` instead of `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken` and the `CAS_STATEFUL_IDENTIFIER` constant got moved to the new class.

The change was made in the commit [Use a Custom Authentication Token for CAS](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/commit/04369cf2da9). Apparently though, the project's [documentation page source](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/6.2.3/docs/modules/ROOT/pages/servlet/authentication/cas.adoc) was left intact, so it is no longer up-to-date with the changed code.

> So, what's the best way to create this UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken?

Provided you don't insist on creating `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken`, you can create a new `CasServiceTicketAuthenticationToken` instead:

```java
token = CasServiceTicketAuthenticationToken.stateful(serviceTicket);
```

While you can surely still create `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken`, it could be a little bit more complicated because the visibility of `CasServiceTicketAuthenticationToken.CAS_STATEFUL_IDENTIFIER` (obtainable via  `token.getPrincipal()` in the example above) is *package-level* now.